# How to properly place Date in <pubdate> element on RSS feed

Tags: rss, feed

I'm using RSS Graffitty to post RSS items to a facebook page.

The app told me the items were missing the publication date so I added this tag:

```
echo "<pubdate>".$row['Date']."</pubdate>";
```

$row['Date'] is obtained from my MySQL database and it's a Datetime column.

How must I format it/echo it so it's recognized by the RSS feed? Must I change the element?

Thanks

Comment: Be careful that you use `pubDate` and not `pubdate`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[RSS 2.0](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) specifications on the `<pubDate>` element should conform to the [RFC 822 Date and Time syntax](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z28). Namely, to display it in the following format:

> Fri, 21 Dec 2012 10:00:01 GMT

If you error run your RSS feed through the [W3C Feed Validator](http://feed2.w3.org/docs/error/InvalidRFC2822Date.html) you'll note these examples of valid RFC822 date-times:

```
<pubDate>Wed, 02 Oct 2002 08:00:00 EST</pubDate>

<pubDate>Wed, 02 Oct 2002 13:00:00 GMT</pubDate>

<pubDate>Wed, 02 Oct 2002 15:00:00 +0200</pubDate>
```

If you wanted to use MySQL formatting, you'd call the column with the following [use of `date_format()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), adjusting the UTC modifier/marker as necessary:

```
date_format(Date, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Or you can do it via the [PHP date method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) with `DATE_RSS` [setting the format](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for you:

```
echo "<pubdate>".date(DATE_RSS, strtotime($row['Date']))."</pubdate>";
```

Make sure your `<pubDate>` element appear within its parent `<item>` node.

Also note that this element is case-sensitive. You must output `pubDate` with the capital D and not all lowercase (`pubdate`) as other elements can.

Comment: The feedvalidator tells me: `Fri, 24 Feb 12 18:11:13 -0700` is wrong. It seems compliant with the example. Do you have any idea why it could be happening? http://feed2.w3.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Flujanventas.com

Comment: Make the year as four digits and that should fix it all up @lis

Comment: It is probably better to use `DATE_RSS` instead of `DATE_RFC822` since in the dates generated by the latter, years are represented by only two digits.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint: the -r switch in the php date function is the shorthand for the RFC 2822 format, which actually does yield a four digit year.

See [PHP Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for reference.