# What is the correct format for RSS feed pubdate?

Tags: php, rss

I'm having trouble getting the date of my RSS Feed to run correctly.  Do you know what the proper date to show it is?

I have it stored in a field called creation_date in this format: 2012-08-14 10:17:12

Then i grab it:

```
$pubDate = $article[creation_date];
```

Then I convert it:

```
$pubDate= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($pubDate));
```

Then within my item tag I place it:

`<pubdate>'.date("l, F d, Y", strtotime($pubDate)).'</pubdate>`

Is there something that I'm not seeing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly place Date in <pubdate> element on RSS feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405309/how-to-properly-place-date-in-pubdate-element-on-rss-feed)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Solved:

```
$pubDate = $article[creation_date]; 
$pubDate= date("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime($pubDate));
```

then in my echo'd code:

```
 <pubDate>'.$pubDate.'</pubDate>
```

Answer (score 74):

The PHP date function has already a way to format pubDate (RFC 2822) compliant dates:

```
date('r', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 22):

See `pubDate` definition in [RSS 2.0 Specification](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html):

> All date-times in RSS conform to the [**Date and Time Specification of RFC 822**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z28), with the exception that the year may be expressed with two characters or four characters (four preferred).

Here are examples of valid RFC822 date-times:

```
<pubDate>Wed, 02 Oct 2002 08:00:00 EST</pubDate>

<pubDate>Wed, 02 Oct 2002 13:00:00 GMT</pubDate>

<pubDate>Wed, 02 Oct 2002 15:00:00 +0200</pubDate>
```

See also [Problematical RFC 822 date-time value](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/ProblematicalRFC822Date.html).

Answer (score 12):

Use this format: `D, d M Y H:i:s O`. See http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Or use DateTime constants for more easy usage: `DateTime::RSS`

Answer (score 12):

Rss `pubDate` uses the [RFC 2822 standards](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt). You can achieve this in `php` by invoking the `r` argument on the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function, i.e:

```
<?php
$pubDate= date('r', time());
echo "<pubDate>$pubDate</pubDate>";
# <pubDate>Thu, 15 Oct 2023 02:46:11 UTC</pubDate>
?>
```

---

If you prefer the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, use:

```
$pubDate = new DateTime();
echo $pubDate->format(DateTime::RSS);
```

Answer (score 6):

What about [**`DateTime`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object that implements [`DateTimeInterface`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php) **(*PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7, PHP 8*)**

```php
\DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTimeInterface::RSS, $RSSDate); // converting RSS date to object
```

or

```php
date(\DateTimeInterface::RSS, $timestamp); // formatting timestamp to RSS time
```

or both

```php
$dto = \DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTimeInterface::RSS, $RSSDate);
date('d-M-Y H:i:s', $dto->getTimestamp()); // formatting RSS date to anything you want
```

or even better

```php
$dto = \DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTimeInterface::RSS, $RSSDate);
$formattedDate = $dto->format('d-M-Y H:i:s');
```

> Constants defined in `\DateTimeInterface` are available through `\DateTime` class as well if you want to save some `use`

Answer (score 5):

While the accepted answer `("D, d M Y H:i:s T")` works as expected most of the time, it is not 100% correct. In multilingual situations this string may give non English text which won't be accepted as RFC compliant. To be always sure that the English version is used, use `"r"`.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest method is to use the DATE_RSS predefined constant (available since PHP 5.1.0).

```
$pubDate = date(DATE_RSS, strtotime($pubDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used like this:

```
$item->date = date('D, d M Y H:i:s GMT', strtotime($myBlogPublishedTime));
```

[my hp rss sample](http://www.matao.me/news/rss/rss.xml)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved to compile a valid RFC-822 datetime for RSS into XSLT:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="now" select="fn:current-dateTime()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($now, '[FNn,3-3], [D01] [MNn,3-3] [Y0001] [H01]:[m01]:[s01] [Z0001]')"/>
```