# Formatting a date-time using Timex

Tags: datetime, elixir

I have a date. How can I format it via Times so that it becomes of the format:

```
Wed, 02 Oct 2002 15:00:00 +0200
```

or

```
Wed, 02 Oct 2002 15:00:00 GMT
```

or

```
Wed, 02 Oct 2002 15:00:00 EST
```

I've tried this:

```
 Timex.format!(my_date, "%D, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s T", :strftime))
```

but it threw an exception:

```
%Timex.Format.FormatError{message: {:format, "Expected end of input at line 1, column 16"}} (expected a string)
```

while it's getting converted into other, simpler, formats with no errors.

Comment: That format string has multiple errors. `%D` is not the day of week and the timezone is `%Z` (or `%z` or other, but not `T`). See https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.Format.DateTime.Formatters.Strftime.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `RFC1123` DateTime format:

```
iex(1)> Timex.now |> Timex.format!("{RFC1123}")
"Sat, 11 Mar 2017 12:04:21 +0000"
iex(2)> Timex.now |> Timex.to_datetime("America/Chicago") |> Timex.format!("{RFC1123}")
"Sat, 11 Mar 2017 06:04:50 -0600"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405309/how-to-properly-place-date-in-pubdate-element-on-rss-feed

Comment: do you know why this `"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"` gives me "Invalid format string, must contain at least one directive."?

Comment: Works for me with `:strftime` as the third argument.

Answer (score 4):

```
Timex.now()|> Timex.format!("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", :strftime)
```

output: 2019-05-23 11:06

Comment: Your output does not match the op's desired output.  And, dredging up an old thread that was already answered to the op's satisfaction deserves another downvote, but alas I can only give one.