# Unable to format a date-time variable properly

Tags: elixir, timex

I'm trying to convert a date-time to a certain format:

```
Timex.format!(my_date_time, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"))
```

which throws an **exception**:

```
 got {:format, "Invalid format string, must contain at least one directive."} 
 while retrieving Exception.message/1 for %Timex.Format.FormatError{message: 
{:format, "Invalid format string, must contain at least one directive."}} (expected a string)
```

Comment: You forgot to pass `:strftime` as the third argument?

Comment: @Dogbert, still fails --> `argument error`

Comment: `Timex.format!(Timex.now, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z", :strftime)` works for me.

Comment: @Dogbert, I pass a date-time from a database in the format `2017-03-10 00:00:00` to it, can this be the cause?

Comment: You're passing a string? You need to pass a `DateTime` struct.

Comment: @Dogbert, ecto.datetime

Comment: @Dogbert, although this works `Timex.format!(my_datetime, "{D}.{M}.{YYYY} {h24}:{m}")`, but it's not what I want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a date-time using Timex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734873/formatting-a-date-time-using-timex)

Comment: This is a typical “why is this code not working” type of question, prohibited here on SO. Besides that, it was an exact copy of the question, that had been posted few hours ago (later edited.) The OP is rude and offensive. I flagged for moderator’s attention and I personally would appreciate if everybody stops helping here.